# Div scrolling and overflow

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a non-scrolling page with a content div that I want to scrolling dynamic to the length of the list as it grows.

The webpage is [scubapolice.com/echo.php](http://www.scubapolice.com/echo.php)

See code below

```
body {
    font-family: "Bitstream Vera Sans",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans,"Bitstream Vera Serif";
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #feffb7;
    background: #000000 url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.middleearth {

    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    margin-left: 19%;
    width: 62%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
    padding: 30px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

#loadin {
    border: 1px solid #cbcd65;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}

<body>

<div class="title">
    SCUBA Police
</div>

<div class="menu">
<div class="menubar">

<?php include 'menu.html';?>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="contain">

<div class="middleearth">
<div class="content">
    <h2>Echo</h2>
    <div id="loadin">

<?php include 'echolist.html';?>

    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<?php include 'footer.html';?>

</body>
```

Problem: I have a scroll bar inside the loadin div but the content still runs below the bottom of the page and I cant actually scroll.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML ? Filling a HTML/CSS snippet in your question realy help.

Comment: remove `overflow-y: hidden;` in your `body`. that causes to your non scrolling page.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. [mcve]

Comment: I dont want the whole page to scroll, only the div with the list of content. I thought I need the hidden overflow tag for the body to prevent the whole page from trying to scroll. I'll try without and see what the behavior is.

Comment: So I definitely do want the overflow: hidden; for the body. When I add a fixed height for my loadin div, it starts to behave the way I would like, but I do not want a fixed height in pixels though because of of how it will behave on different screen sizes and resolutions. But if I add a percentage height, it doesn't work. Hmmm any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your overflow, the problem is your 'loadin' height,
try this snippet with a fixed height :

```css
body {
    font-family: "Bitstream Vera Sans",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans,"Bitstream Vera Serif";
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #feffb7;
    background: #000000 url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.middleearth {

    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    margin-left: 19%;
    width: 62%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
    padding: 30px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

#loadin {
    border: 1px solid #cbcd65;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="title">
    SCUBA Police
</div>

<div class="menu">
<div class="menubar">


    </div>
</div>

<div id="contain">

<div class="middleearth">
<div class="content">
    <h2>Echo</h2>
    <div id="loadin">
      lorem ipsum <br/>
      lorem ipsum <br/>
      lorem ipsum <br/>
      lorem ipsum <br/>
      lorem ipsum <br/>
      lorem ipsum <br/>
      lorem ipsum <br/>
      lorem ipsum <br/>
      lorem ipsum <br/>
      lorem ipsum <br/>
      lorem ipsum <br/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works with a fixed height. I'll just need to figure out the best way to set a height that will still be dynamic for different screens and resolutions...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fixed your content then you need to specify height like 500px;

```css
body {
font-family: "Bitstream Vera Sans",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans,"Bitstream Vera Serif";
font-size: 1em;
color: #feffb7;
background: #000000 url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
margin: 0px;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
.middleearth {

background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
margin-left: 19%;
width: 62%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
padding: 30px;
padding-top: 1px;
}

#loadin {
border: 1px solid #cbcd65;
overflow: scroll;
height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="title">
    SCUBA Police
</div>

<div class="menu">
<div class="menubar">

<?php include 'menu.html';?>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="contain">

<div class="middleearth">
<div class="content">
    <h2>Echo</h2>
    <div id="loadin">

<?php include 'echolist.html';?>

    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<?php include 'footer.html';?>

</body>
```